# Photoshop batch job: export to folder (filenames)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing

I'm trying to run a batch file on a custom action. The action does one thing: File -> Export -> Paths to Illustrator.

However, whenever I run that action as a batch on multiple files, it saves each file with the same name. So if I open `File1.psd` and save it as `working/File1.ai`, then run the batch on `File2.psd`, `File3.psd`, and `File4.psd`, what I get is `working/File1.ai` as an Illustrator file exported from `File4.psd`. Files 2 and 3 have been overwritten (as was `File1.ai`, obviously).

Here's my Batch dialog:
[image: Screen shot of Batch dialog box]

If I change the destination to e.g. Folder, it re-saves all the files as PSD in addition to overwriting the AI files. How can I run this export on an arbitrary number of PSD files and get the same number of AI files out the other end?

EDIT: re-recording the action and refusing the dialog box gets me the dialog box on the first run of the batch, and subsequent files saved under the name I provide in that dialog (in other words, one dialog box for all files).

EDIT 2: Following the answer below, I tried saving to Folder and overriding action save commands (screen shot):
[image: second try batch process dialog]

This produced the same results. :(

Here's the action I'm running:
[image: action definition screen shot]

ETA 3: Based on the comments, my problem might be that the Export -> Paths to Illustrator command does not honor the "Override Action Save As" checkbox, which means I'm just stuck with that shortcoming of Photoshop.

Comment: How familiar are you with javascript etc.?

Comment: It's not my first language, but I get along. Part of the end goal of these scripts is to get path strings I can use in Raphael.js.

Comment: OK, see my answer.

Comment: Downvotes: care to offer constructive criticism?

Answer (score 1):

Choose a destination folder (last not-grayed out option) then choose ' override action save as' below it. You can see that below *that*, it says 'Starting serial#' which indicates it'll name each file with a next number.

Comment: Hmm. I tried this, and I get the same behavior as before. I'll add a screen shot of the action I'm running, maybe that will help...

Comment: Strange it works for me.. It's probably a little detail you're doing differently.

Comment: Yeah, that little detail is what I need to figure out. :( If only I could edit the action directly!

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your batch dialog so I can look for differences?

Comment: Wait, I'm a bit confused now that I'm reading this again. I've used batch before but never for exporting to Illustrator, and when i open the batch screen, it doesn't give me this option. How'd you get there? (p.s. I might need to alter/delete my answer if I'm totally off track here)

Comment: Neither do I have a 'Sylvius'  set..

Comment: I think "export" does not honor the "save-as override" since it is not a "save as" command. I do know from personal experience that a "save for web" action is not affected by this

Comment: But how did you get there, with the option to save to Illustrator? `File > Automate > Batch..` I suppose?

Comment: @poepje: don't be confused by the drop-down with "Export to Illustrator." That is the name of a custom action.

Comment: pjmorse, I have created a chatroom about this, would you care to join? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/3776/photoshop-batch-job-export-to-folder-filenames?tab=general

Comment: Sorry, I was on the road when you posted the chatroom comment. To answer your comments: The "Sylvius" set is just a set in the Photoshop actions window (create by clicking the folder icon). "Export to Illustrator" is just the name of the action I created - I could have named it "my custom action" or "Elliot". My third screen shot shows the action, which is very simple.

Comment: @horatio, it sounds like this is my problem (that "export" doesn't honor the "save-as override"). What I need is to figure out how to get around it.

Comment: Just to clarify, in CS6, *some* export functions do respect the "save-as override" when used with "Serial Number". If the function you're using doesn't, then @horatio's answer below is a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

One way to work with this is to use scripting (applescript, vbscript, javascript). Phtoshop exposes the export command (`exportDocument (exportIn [, exportAs][, options])`) (see for instance adobe's document `photoshop_cs4_javascript_ref.pdf` ) and so all you need to do is open a document and then feed the command a destination filename and options.

A quick google search brought me to this script from Photoshop for Geeks (http://www.tranberry.com/panels/) NOT MY CODE:

```
// openFolderTemplate.jsx
// Copyright 2007
// Written by Jeffrey Tranberry
// Photoshop for Geeks Version 1.0

/* 
Description:
This script is a template script that will
open and process a folder of images
*/

// enable double clicking from the 
// Macintosh Finder or the Windows Explorer
#target photoshop

// Make Photoshop the frontmost application
// in case we double clicked the file
app.bringToFront();


///////////////////////////
//       SET-UP          //
///////////////////////////


// A list of file extensions to skip, keep them lower case

    gFilesToSkip = Array( "db", "xmp", "thm", "txt", "doc", "md0", "tb0", "adobebridgedb", "adobebridgedbt", "bc", "bct" );


// Pops open a dialog for the user to
// choose the folder of documents to process

    var inputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder of documents to process");


// Pops open a dialog for the user to
// set the output folder

    var outputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder for the output files");



///////////////////////
//         MAIN          //
//////////////////////



// Open Folder of Images

    OpenFolder();


// show the path to an output folder

    alert(outputFolder);



///////////////////////////
//       FUNCTIONS       //
///////////////////////////



// Given the a Folder of files, open them

function OpenFolder() {
        var filesOpened = 0;
        var fileList = inputFolder.getFiles();
        for ( var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++ ) {
                   // Make sure all the files in the folder are compatible with PS
                if ( fileList[i] instanceof File && ! fileList[i].hidden && ! IsFileOneOfThese( fileList[i], gFilesToSkip )) {
                        open( fileList[i] );
                        filesOpened++;


                    /////////////////////////////////////
                    // Put all your processing functions... //
                    /////////////////////////////////////

                        // Alert and show the document name
                        alert(app.activeDocument.name);

                        // Cloes the file without saving
                        app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);

                    ////////////////////////////////////////////
                    // ...in the area between these two comments. //
                    ////////////////////////////////////////////


                }

        }
        return filesOpened;
}


// given a file name and a list of extensions
// determine if this file is in the list of extensions

function IsFileOneOfThese( inFileName, inArrayOfFileExtensions ) {
    var lastDot = inFileName.toString().lastIndexOf( "." );
    if ( lastDot == -1 ) {
        return false;
    }
    var strLength = inFileName.toString().length;
    var extension = inFileName.toString().substr( lastDot + 1, strLength - lastDot );
    extension = extension.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < inArrayOfFileExtensions.length; i++ ) {
        if ( extension == inArrayOfFileExtensions[i] ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can pick a source and destination folder, and the script will enumerate the files. You can then insert your own function to `do magic`.

Comment: Does that also work for Illustrator? ^

Comment: Illustrator does support scripting, but my guess is that the script above would not work without alterations in illustrator. Adobe hosts documentation about the scripting model in general and for individual products.

Comment: @user20375 - I submitted an edit to the answer for the Photoshop scripting reference, but here's the corresponding link for Illustrator (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html). Since Illustrator doesn't open files quite the same way as PS, line 16 (#target photoshop) and line 77 (open( fileList[i] );) would change, and obviously your specific action/processing.